# Unwrap mesh with spherical projection in python

Tags: python, scripting, uv, bmesh

I would like to have the same result with python as in the UI when I do unwrap > sphere projection on a mesh.

I know it's possible to use the operator `bpy.ops.uv.sphere_project()` – as mentioned in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-uv-unwrap-object-with-python) – but I'd rather use the low-level (bmesh?) alternative, if any.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10444/15861

Comment: Yeah I saw this one too but that doesn't help much here. I suppose there is no answer to this question until a python blender guru looks at it. This is a shame that features in the UI cannot be replicated without using it in bare python...

Comment: The low-level alternative here is to calculate the map yourself, which, in all likelihood, will be slower than simply using the operator. Doing things via low level commands is usually a good idea, but not always :)

Comment: It's a wee bit strange to speak about "low-level" in a high level language. I don't want to do low-level stuff, I merely wish to call the function that the operator in the UI uses to do the same, without anything on the scene. I use curves to mesh some objects and at no point in time I need to link to scene, which tremendously helps when you have thousands of objects.

Comment: Of course I link to scene when meshing is done. And the uv unwrapping is one of the last steps that may be automated.

Answer (score -1):

In Blender 2.9 the Python for calling this is
`bpy.ops.uv.sphere_project()`